# Ajax call on mouse hovering on links

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, mouseover, hyperlink

I am showing some information on mouse hovering on the links. I am doing this by making an AJAX call on mouse hover the the links and fetching the data from database.

Problem is that if I mouse hover several times on the same link it will make the AJAX call and hit the database in each time. But I want if it once fetch the data from the database for a specific link on second time mouse hover it should not hit the database again. For this I need to store the data in client side some where and reuse it(I think).

What is the best approach to handle this situation? Can any one suggest me the solutions?

P.S: I am having more than 20 such links in the page.

Answer (score 0):

use the `One` function, it guarantees that the call gets executed once.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the information in a hidden field or fields. On the first request, just check if the requested info is already available in there, and if not, hit the database.

Comment: How to do this can you explain a more?

Answer (score 0):

May this will be a wrong way but you can do this in this way:

Define class attribute for the anchor tag and change the class to true to false after loading data from database when someone click this link again check the class name what it indicates true or false in this way you can do

```
<a class="load-true"></a>
```

after loading data

```
<a class="load-false"></a>
```

and check class to load data.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

on the JavaScript side, use a hash table where the keys correspond to the IDs of links that have been hovered.  You only call the DB when inserting a new key (as in allHovers[curHover]++; )  A side benefit of this is that you would have a list & count of hovers that you can reference at any time.